# need to dynamically insert attachment to an access form from a local system and save the address into a table

Tags: ms-access, vba

Hey i am new to access database.
I am creating a form in which i need to attach a excel file from the local system. I tried to use the attachment control to attach the document. But i am not able to store it into a table. I need to use that excel document for my further processing. I need to get the path from which the data is selected from my local system.
I hard coded the path and i was able to do my operation but now i need to dynamically fetch the data from the location.

thanks in advance

My code for hard coding looks like this

```
    Private Sub Command4_Click()

Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Set dbs = CurrentDb
If (ifTableExists("featuretable") = True) Then
dbs.Execute "Delete * from  featuretable"
End If
Dim filepath As String
filepath = "C:\Users\jolly@iese.fhg.de\Desktop\featurevalues.xlsx"**
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , "featuretable", filepath, True
fmfeaturesubform.Form.Requery

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Attach" and "import" are completely different things. i guess you want to import the excel sheet.
one way would be use the Application.FileDialog:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196794(v=office.15).aspx

another way would be search your current folder and import matching filenames:

```
    Dim mBaseFolder As String
    Dim mFname as string
    mBaseFolder = "C:\test\" ' or application.CurrentProject.Path
    mFname = Dir(mBaseFolder & "*.xls")

    Do While fname <> ""
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , "featuretable", mFname , True
        mFname = dir()
    Loop
```